# Oracion de dos palabras almacenada en var Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Si guardo una oración que siempre va a estar formada por una o dos palabras en una variable *var* como hago para guardar la primera palabra en una variable y la segunda en otra, en caso que la oracion sea de dos palabras, y  para saber eso (si la oracion almanacenada en *var* es de una o dos palabras) como puedo hacer un if?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la función `split()` de javascript, si la oración esta separada por espacios agrega `(" ")` si es un carácter diferente por ejemplo comas `var cad="hola,adios"` usa `.split(",")`

> Documentacion [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)

```
var str = "hola adios";
var res = str.split(" "); 
var cont=0;
res.forEach(function(element) {
    cont++;
});
if(cont==2){
    var cad1=res[0];
    var cad2=res[1];
}else if(cont==1){
    var cad1=res[0];
}else{
    //si es diferente a 1 o 2
}
```